# Копирование данных из Access 2016 в Microsoft SQL Server 2014 средствами VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Как скопировать данные из локальной таблицы Access в таблицу на SQL server если имена столбцов не совпадают.  типы данных одинаковые, но на SQL server на один столбец(счетчик) больше.

Comment: А запросом... `INSERT INTO sql_table (fieldnames except identity) SELECT fieldnames FROM access_table`

Comment: Пробовал, запрос я отправлял из VBA по ADO соединение(так же пробовал DAO) и получаю ошибку, что сервер SQL не видит таблицу Access.

Comment: А не надо выполнять запрос на сервере. Выполняйте его на клиенте. Т.е. просто присоедините к базе таблицу с SQL-сервера (мастером связанных таблиц), и гоните туда данные запросом Аксесса. По завершении - не забудьте отсоединить.

Comment: При присоединении таблицы с сервера, Access почему-то меняет тип некоторых полей ( а именно поля с датой он превращает в короткий текст), причем данных в таблице на сервере нет, она пустая. В этом то и вся проблема, кроме этих полей все остальное работает по предложенной вами схеме.

Comment: Ну так и копируйте дату, явно преобразуя ее в текст в формате, который будет корректно распознан SQL-сервером как дата (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: Картина такая получается, на SQL server поле имеет тим данных дата, когда делаешь связанную таблицу в Access то это же поле уже является коротким текстом, а в таблице из которой надо копировать  это же поле имеет тип данных дата. Не понимаю что с этим делать. Потому как если вставить в привязанную таблицу в это поле дату как текст, но выдает ошибку что SQL server ожидает дату...уже несколько дней бьюсь. Помогите примером или ткните носом в мануал...

Comment: *когда делаешь связанную таблицу в Access то это же поле уже является коротким текстом* Вообще этот момент очень странный. Сейчас у меня просто нет нигде в доступе MS SQL - но одно время приходилось работать плотно именно связывая таблицы в Аксесс, и с несоответствием типов полей ни разу не сталкивался. А какой тип поля ТОЧНО в SQL server? должен быть datetime, a не datetime2.

Comment: Вот я тоже не понимаю как так, на SQL server тип данных date

Comment: *на SQL server тип данных date* MS Access не имеет типа данных, эквивалентного типу данных date у SQL server. См. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: вот же, все так просто оказалось...спасибо вам огромное